Porting working python 3.6 prog to python 3.8 causes isinstance to yield False depending on where the type is imported from
My prog is a railway nodes graph ported up to python 3.6 without problems. I am now porting to python 3.8 (i.e. the latest my Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS supports) and I am experiencing imho weird behaviour of "isinstance". Here is a screenshot of my IPython session:
In [10]: rf.line_object_add_signal_box(lb.z055,5,lengths[0])
object Redgate Mill Junction at pos 5 is not a controllable object

In [11]: type(lb.z055.z5)
Out[11]: railref.railref.lineobj.JC

In [12]: isinstance(lb.z055.z5,rf.ICTL)
Out[12]: False

In [13]: isinstance(lb.z055.z5,rf.railref.lineobj.ICTL)
Out[13]: True

In [14]: isinstance(lb.z055.z5,rf.JC)
Out[14]: False

In [15]: isinstance(lb.z055.z5,rf.railref.lineobj.JC)
Out[15]: True

The function line_object_add_signal_box tries to add a signal box node to a node object implementing ICTL, i.e. having a self.ct member. The receiving node is a JC object, a railway junction, which obviously has a signal box in control.
The checks I have run are to be seen in clauses In [11] to In [15].
The structure of the object system is such that all nodes are in the package railref.railref.lineobj. These are imported into the IPython session by importing * from the top __init__.py as rf.
Now the strange thing happens, that although clause In [11] holds, you can see in clauses In [12] and In [14] that the import as rf via the __init__.py is not accepted by isinstance, whereas the semi-fully-qualified ones in clauses In [13] and In [15] are.
This anomaly has bitten me as well, when trying to get isinstance of other types.
IMHO this is a bug, as the objects all have the same absolute type.
To make things worse, I have seen this behaviour disappear after closing the IPython session and starting afresh.
Does someone have an explanation of this ?
Thx, Michiel.

Please include text as text, not as an image.

For debugging help, you need to make a [mre]. Without seeing the code (imports, definitions), the best we can do is guess. And everything needs to be provided as text, not a picture

I understand your question, but it will take me some time to reproduce a similar situation as an example.

As far as I can see, this answer seems to be the solution. I did not find this when searching.

And indeed, I extracted a list of sys.modules, and both railref and railref.railref.lineobj are in this list. When importing railref as rf it seems that you get different classes from both. And now find the proper way to do it, because it has to provide easy typing in my IPython session, preventing to have to type fully qualified class names all the time.

The real reason is given in PEP366: rf and rf.railref.lineobj have different __package__ values, so they are fundamentally different. The solution seems to be using relative imports everywhere.

And the reason for the disappearance of this phenomenon is, that on restart of the IPython session, all node objects are freshly loaded from a json repository, which saves the node type as a qualified class name string.

And indeed, after changing all imports to relative ones, the problem has been solved
